# BoonEx Dolphin: Alter the Add a New Group form

Tags: php, boonex-dolphin

When adding a new group in [BoonEx Dolphin](http://www.boonex.com/dolphin/), there is an HTML form that contains several input fields. Among the fields, there are `Country`, `City`, `Zip/Postal Code` - how can I remove those from the form?

Comment: Who or what is Boonex Dolphin?

Comment: Ah, [okay](http://www.boonex.com/). Hmm, I'd say you may be better off with their [community support](http://www.boonex.com/trac/dolphin/wiki). The general answer is yes, it's probably possible but the people familiar with that piece of software are the most likely to be able to tell you quickly where to find the right file.

Answer (score -1):

Group/Add Group/ Group'sInfo

Here is the answer for your question. Refer this link.

edit the file "modules/boonex/events/classes/BxEventsFormAdd.php"

here you see this for country:

```
'Country' => array(
'type' => 'select',
'name' => 'Country',
'caption' => _t('_bx_events_caption_country'),
'values' => $aCountries,
'required' => true,
'checker' => array (
'func' => 'preg',
'params' => array('/^[a-zA-Z]{2}$/'),
'error' => _t ('_bx_events_err_country'),
),                                       
'db' => array (
'pass' => 'Preg',
'params' => array('/([a-zA-Z]{2})/'),
),                   
),
```

delete the line:

```
'required' => true,
```

same for city and place, or you could try to delete the whole code from above

for groups the same on the file:

modules/boonex/groups/classes/BxGroupsFormAdd.php

Here is the link for more details:

http://www.boonex.com/forums/topic/Remove-Country-from-mandatory-field-in-Groups-and-Events.htm